# How to install unison from source on macOS

Tags: macos, unison

I was wondering whether somebody managed to install [unison](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison)'s latest version from source, on its macOS machine (Here I am trying with Catalina). I followed the steps here :

1. I verified that I had XCode installed (otherwise forget about compiling anything :)
2. I cloned the official Git repository by running

   `git clone https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison.git`
3. I moved to the newly created directory `unison`

   `cd unison`
4. As mentionned in the documentation I then ran the `make` command telling it to build the text UI:

   `make UISTYLE=text`

Result should have been an executable file called `unison`but instead of this I got the following error :

```
Blablabla$ make UISTYLE=text
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C src UISTYLE=text
UISTYLE = text
Building for Unix
NATIVE = true
THREADS = false
STATIC = false
OSTYPE =
OSARCH = osx
ocamlopt: ubase/rx.mli ---> ubase/rx.cmi
ocamlopt -g -unsafe-string -I lwt -I ubase -I system -I fsmonitor -I fsmonitor/linux -I fsmonitor/windows -I system/generic -I lwt/generic -ccopt -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -c /Users/Shared/unison/src/ubase/rx.mli
make[1]: ocamlopt: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [ubase/rx.cmi] Error 1
make: *** [text] Error 2
```

5. I then wondered whether XCode might not carry with him an [OCaml compiler](https://ocaml.org/docs/install.html#MacPorts-MacPorts). So I installed the official one using [MacPort](https://www.macports.org) therefore running:

```
sudo port install ocaml
sudo port install opam
```

6. I then rerun the same `make` command

   `make UISTYLE=text`
7. This time the result looked better and ended with:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make tags
if [ -f "`which etags`" ]; then \
        etags *.mli */*.mli *.ml */*.ml */*.m *.c */*.c *.txt \
             *Makefile* \
      ; fi
```

8. However, still no `unison` file visible anywhere.

Question is ... since there is no error message, where is this executable?

Answer (score 1):

Re-hello people from the Internet,

I managed to help myself here and got a nice and fresh `unison` executable on my macOS Catalina computer.

Basically, the base `make` tries to move the compilation product into `/Users/<your_user>/bin/.` which makes sense I guess, but is rarely used by us macOS users. So here is what I did to fix the issue :

1. Create the `bin` directory into your home

   `mkdir ~/bin`
2. Re run the `make` by doing

   `make UISTYLE=text`
3. Verify you have the executable by asking its version:

   `~/bin/unison -version`
4. Happy me, I got the expected message back from my terminal:

   `unison version 2.51.3 (ocaml 4.08.1)`

Hope it can help somebody.